# how to move table rows by using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code

```
<tr class="parentRow">
    <td colspan="2">parentTd 01 </td>
</tr>

<tr class="childRow">
        <td> childTd 01 </td>

</tr>
<tr class="childRow">
        <td> childTd 02 </td>
</tr>


<tr class="parentRow">
    <td colspan="2">parentTd 02 </td>
</tr>

<tr class="childRow">
        <td> childTd 03 </td>
</tr>

<tr class="childRow">
        <td> childTd 04 </td>
</tr>
```

And by using jQuery, I want to create a function that will move only **childRow** inside **parentRow** to get a result designed by this code

```
<tr class="parentRow">
    <td colspan="2">parentTd 01 </td>
</tr>

<tr class="childRow">
        <td> childTd 02 </td>
</tr>
<tr class="childRow">
        <td> childTd 01 </td>
</tr>


<tr class="parentRow">
    <td colspan="2">parentTd 02 </td>
</tr>

<tr class="childRow">
        <td> childTd 04 </td>
</tr>

<tr class="childRow">
        <td> childTd 03 </td>
</tr>
```

Any idea? Sorry if you find my question might not been clear enough!!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the jquery ui `.sortable()` for this..

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HpE2X/)***

Comment: Thanks for your help @Codegiant but it doesn't work, I'm trying to solve this problem, and if only I find the solution, I'll post it